# 3SKey signing for EBICS implementation

Tags: c#, signing

I am trying to build a EBICS client in c#. I am not clear about the signing of the documents using 3SKey. Where do i get the signing certificate? I have read the 3s key service description, but it is not clear to me on how to proceed with this.

Should I install any component from Swift portal on the client machine?

Comment: Look at source code of GITHUB project : https://github.com/hohlerde/NetEbics  The software interface is web so you have to make sure your Browser is setup properly.  See : https://www2.swift.com/3skey/help/browser_support.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for the good reference articles. Can you also share some information about accessing the token. Do I need the USB at all after installing the browser extension. Apologies if some questions are basic. I am struggling a bit to understand the signing using USB tokens.

Comment: If you were given the USB it may contain the crypto key to use during login.  The USB may also contain a certificate that got installed.  I'm not an expert for this tool to be able to give an answer.  So I can't answer if you always need to install USB.  You can try without USB and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

You will need the 3skey certificate and use it in the X509 Ebics attributes.

You can read more information in the following document about 3skey token and certificates:
https://www2.swift.com/knowledgecentre/rest/v1/publications/3sk_ptl_ug_corp/3.0/3sk_ptl_ug_corp.pdf?logDownload=true

the 3skey is a hardware key (USB) so you need to use SConnect extension in your browser.

Hope this helps